# Regex split on comma but ignoring when inside text qualifier containing two characters

Tags: c#, regex

I've seen a lot of examples of splitting on a comma and ignoring those commas which are inside single or double quotes. I am looking for a similar thing, however instead of being single or double quote I need the text qualifier to be ~*

I attempted to modify some of the code I found that used double quote as a text qualifier but was unsuccessful. I am terrible with regex and have spent sometime today looking at the documentation to understand it so I could try to create an expression that would work for my use.

Is this possible to have two characters as the text qualifier?

example of one of the lines:

```
~* header1~*, ~* header2 ~*, ~* header3, value1 ~*
```

I am looking for the output to be:

```
 ~* header1~*, 
 ~* header2~*, 
 ~* header3,value1~*

var result = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in two lines.

`First replace all of the alone "~* " by using this expression "~\*\s", and replace it with a space, " ".` (This gets rid of the ~* that aren't new lines)

```
Then secondly split on "~\*,"
```

EDIT:

You should be able to split using this expression `"(?<=(~\*,))\s"`

Comment: I will give this a shot. However I forgot to mention that I want to keep the ~* as text qualifiers and will update my question

Comment: @KevinMee I added an edit that produces your output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one single regular expression to achieve the desired output:

```
/~\*(.*)~\*[,\s]*/gU
```

Each capturing group will then contain one string. Have a look a working example: https://www.regex101.com/r/zP3aM3/2

Comment: unfortunately there will be some tilde in some of the data.

Comment: I've updated my answer, and the example at https://www.regex101.com/r/zP3aM3/2 shows a working example with tildes within the strings.

Answer (score 1):

No need Split.

```
string input = "~* header1~*, ~* header2 ~*, ~* header3, value1 ~*";
string pattern = @"~\* \s* .+? \s* ~\*";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: Close.. this misses a few cases. I am checking the header column count against each row column count and a few rows are not passing.